# Menu item title overriding setTitle in module

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I've encountered a scenario where the menu item Title specified on the Joomla back-end in Menu Manager overrides the following call: `JFactory::getDocument()->setTitle('Custom title')`

The document's title becomes 'Custom title' up until the following lines in `components/com_content/views/article/view.html.php`:

```
if (empty($title)) {
    $title = $this->item->title;
}
$this->document->setTitle($title);
```

I assign a new title to the document in my module:

```
JFactory::getDocument()->setTitle('New title');
```

How can I stop Joomla from overwriting the article I gave the document in my module?

Comment: Might want to check with the folks at http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: There is a similar question at: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31454079/1983389

Answer (score 1):

You Can Use Javascript from your module:

Note me Please If This Code Helps you :)

```
JFactory::getDocument()->addScriptDeclaration("     
        window.onload=function(){
          changeTitle('New Title')
        }

        function changeTitle(newTitle){
            document.title=newTitle;            
        }       
    ");
```