# Set page title in Joomla! 3 from a module

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I have an existing module, which I display from an article by using {loadposition custom_position}. The article is linked to a menu item. I want to be able to set a customized page title from this module, overwriting the page title set by the menu item.

I tried using

```
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->setTitle('Set your title here');
```

But it does not set the page title.

Is it possible to set the page title from within a module, or can it only be done within a component.

Comment: What routing are you doing around your link in the module? You could probably use a custom router and set he options.

Comment: The question at http://stackoverflow.com/q/24865448/1983389 is similar and has an alternative answer using JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

The code you wrote is correct, but maybe other modules / plugins are changing the title after you change it.

You may want to echo the title immediately after you set it, e.g.

```
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->setTitle('Set your title here');
echo "<h1>" . JFactory::getDocument()->getTitle() . "</h1>";
```

If that is correct, you need to look for other modules / plugins that change it later.

Comment: Thanks Francesco. You are right. The title returned by the echo statement is what I set.  Therefore it must be overwritten later, probably by com_content, which is what I am using to display the article.  I'll still need to figure out whether there is a way to stop com_content from overwriting the title.

Comment: I fear you cannot. One way to do it is to write a plugin for that and make it executes at the right time, but that requires a bit more work.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create a "Hide Menu";
2. Create the page link in this Menu;
3. Change the page title in Menu item without any code line...

Comment: Thanks Max.  This will set a static page title, but I am looking to dynamically set the page title from the module.